# Does Social Studio listening support listening to external facebook page posts or public facebook posts?

Tags: marketing-cloud, social, social-content

Salesforce mentioned that, As of October 2015 Facebook changed how they allow keyword matched content to be pulled in. Now any page you wish to pull in posts from need to be set up in a source filter.

In this recent October release of the social studio, again salesforce mentioned that

"Social Studio will no longer receive page posts from Facebook using source groups beginning October 17, 2017. Page posts, comments and replies using Social Studio will only be available through an admin account for the page using a Facebook Social Account."

Does this mean that the social studio listening can no longer listen to any public Facebook posts or pages except to the page for which we have the admin account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for my question. There is new product and service notification email from Salesforce on 23rd october saying that there is no change to how a user of Social Studio can use source groups to receive unowned page posts on Facebook.

They have worked with facebook and resolved the issue. Here is the notification email

[image]